# Wrapping a C code that use OpenCV for image processing to be used with Python that also use OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv

This is maybe kind of a dumb question, but I need to know. So, I am not that good in programming, still learning. Pardon me if this question is somewhat unrealistic.

There is this person who use C++ with OpenCV for his image processing algorithm, and I don't think he is that good in programming, that is he only knows what he should know for his project. And I was told to kind of cooperate with that person to make a project. The other person will use his already developed image processing algorithm in C++ (with OpenCV of course).

The problem is I am using OpenCV with Python. Is it possible, or even logical to wrap his code to be called with Python (which means I will need to learn the way of wrapping C++ code) or much better to ask that person to learn some Python and just translate and move what he has done to Python?

Comment: There is no language C/C++. Only the two **different** languages C and C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Porting code

The distinction between C and C++ code is very important. OpenCV has different APIs for each language, and the C API is rapidly [becoming deprecated](http://answers.opencv.org/question/17546/opencv-will-drop-c-api-support-soon/) as C++ powers ahead as the language of choice. Make sure you are aware which API is in use.

Besides this, porting OpenCV code from one C++ to Python is usually straightforward. The APIs are similar and the vast majority of C++ functions correspond to a Python wrapper.

For example, [calcHist](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html):

> C++: void calcHist(const Mat* **images**, int **nimages**, const int* **channels**, InputArray **mask**, OutputArray **hist**, int **dims**, const int* **histSize**, const float** **ranges**, bool **uniform**=true, bool **accumulate**=false )
>
> Python: cv2.calcHist(**images**, **channels**, **mask**, **histSize**, **ranges**[, **hist**[, **accumulate**]]) → **hist**

As with many Python versions of OpenCV functions, you can see a few main differences:

- There is no need for parameters such as **nimages** (represents the number of images) due to Python's internal tracking of list sizes.
- Where there would be an output parameter in the C++ function (e.g. **hist**), the Python function will often give this as a return value.

Given the detail of the online OpenCV documentation, you may be able to port C++ code to Python yourself without much knowledge of C++ itself. This is probably faster than getting your collaborator to learn a whole new language in order to port his code, especially given your prior experience in the target language.

### Pros of porting

- Your entire project is maintained using a single language.
- The benefits of Python (rapid development; no compiling; etc.) are available throughout the project.

### Cons of porting

- You will likely find that Python code usually runs slower than C++ code, because it is high-level and interpreted. The extent of this problem depends on how much processing is done outside of OpenCV.
- Porting code takes substantial time and effort.

---

## Wrapping existing code

The other option is to use the existing C++ code in a Python binding, which comes with its own advantages and disadvantages. There are a [number of different options](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages) available to you in this case.

### Pros of wrapping

- Quick process - if the C++ code provides a good interface.
- The performance of the C++ code is unaffected.

### Cons of wrapping

- If the C++ code doesn't provide a good interface, it will be painful to wrap it for use in Python.
- The project is maintained using two different languages.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful indeed!